# how to make app to open in a non-fullscreen mode

Tags: flutter, xcode, dart

[click to chat app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ym4s.png)
I want my Flutter app to open in a rectangular window, with my background showing behind it. I tried using code I found online
`SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: []);),` 
but it didn't work.